# Automate Htpasswd command with variables for username and password

Tags: web, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, .htpasswd

I am trying to pass the username and password via a variable within a script:

```
htpasswd -b -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd $HtUser $HtPwd
```

Where HtUser and HtPwd are variables that are populated earlier in the script.  I tried the following ...

```
htpasswd -b -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd '$HtUser' '$HtPwd'
```

But is set the user to be "$HtUser" and password "$HtPwd".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes, or no quotes at all,  in your shell if you want to interpolate variables.  Single quotes don't work.